# How to stop Javadoc from using fully qualified name?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-10

I'm using the Javadoc tool to document some code, and the results uses fully qualified names for system classes, such as `java.lang.String`.  Is there a way to stop that specifically for classes in the `java.*` and `javax.*` heirarchy?

For example, a method definition like this:

```
    * @param field String to write.
    * @throws IOException If the underlying stream throws an exception.
    */
   public void writeField( String field ) throws IOException {
      // etc.
```

Produces Javadoc output like this:

```
writeField

public void writeField​(java.lang.String field) throws java.io.IOException

    ...etc.

Parameters:
    field - String to write.
Throws:
    java.io.IOException - If the underlying stream throws an exception.
```

I'd like the reference to `java.lang.String` to be just `String`, and the reference to `java.io.IOException` likewise to be just `IOException`.

Any ideas?

---

Edit and update re. the accepted answer below:

In NetBeans 10, what I did to fix this was go to the Project view, then switch to Files view.  Then in the project files, locate `nbproject/project.properties` and open that file (right click, choose open).

In the properties view, scroll down on the left until you see `javadoc.additionalparam`.  Then add the following to the right side of that property (in my case its value was empty) `-link https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/`

Then save (control-S) the file and build.  The Javadocs now look how I wanted.  Thank you Slaw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc outputs the fully qualified name if it can't link to the class/method/etc. For it to just output the simple name you must link to the external Javadoc. This is done via the [`-link <url>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javadoc.html#GUID-9D532574-1CDB-4D30-99F3-A308DCAEE55F__GUID-29EABEE0-310E-4131-9577-8B2CE569992A) command line option of the `javadoc` tool. To link to SE classes (i.e. `java.*` and `javax.*`), one option is to use:

```
javadoc -link https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/ [...]
```

Where `[...]` is the rest of the command line. You can change the URL to point to a different version of Java (e.g. Java 8 instead of Java 11).

There's also a `-linkoffline <url1> <url2>` option.

*Note: I believe both options are provided by the "Standard doclet". If not using the standard doclet these options may not be available or may work differently.*

Comment: Worked, thanks!  I updated the question to show what I actually did in NetBeans.