# IntelliJ Javadoc -link option grayed out

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411185/how-to-stop-javadoc-from-using-fully-qualified-name), in order to make Javadocs that don't include fully qualified `@link`s, like this:

[image: Fully Qualified Links in generated Javadoc]

then one needs to add the `-link` option to the call to the `javadoc` executable. In my version of IntelliJ, however (`17.0.7+10-b829.16 amd64`), as you can see the option is grayed out.

[image: -link option grayed out in IntelliJ Javadoc creation dialogue.]

Fiddling around with the various options in that dialogue doesn't seem to fix the issue. I hesitate to send this to the IntelliJ team directly in case it's an issue with how my `javadoc` executable is configured and not with the IDE. If it helps, I'm on a Linux Mint machine with `javadoc` version 17.0.6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Documentation path for the selected SDk. Open "Project Structure | SDKs" and add path on "Documentation Paths" tab.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the Documentation Path for the COrretto 17 JDK, which I am using, and set it to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/. However, the paths to various classes, like `ResponseEntity`, are still rendered in their fully qualified form. Any ideas?